# GPU not recognised

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have just moved over to Windows 10 (from Mac) and can't get my GPU to show up in Blender's Cycles Compute devices either under CUDA or OptiX ("No compatible GPUs found for path tracing").

I have an Nvidia RTX 2080Ti and have installed the current Nvidia Studio Driver (v456.38) and CUDA 11.1.

Running Blender 2.90.1

New to Windows so it may be something really basic I'm missing. Any help greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: I guess there is a bug with the studio driver, had the same issue, I think I did install the regular one and that was working out of the box. If so and you have the time, please consider to report that as a bug.

Comment: I have tried the game driver too and no joy.